# how to calculate the mean in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have captured data using a Shimmer for three different types of fall. A trip, weak and strong fall. I have broken these into sub plots and now I need to calculate the mean. I am new to Matlab and don't understand how to calculate the mean of each of the below:

```
subplot(3,1,1), plot(weak(:,2:4));
subplot(3,1,2), plot(Trip(800:1600,2:4));
subplot(3,1,3), plot(Strong(:,2:4));
```

Do i just need to do something like:

```
 subplot(3,1,1), plot mean(weak(:,2:4));
```

I am totally lost here, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: It's easy either way, but do you want the time average of each graph or the mean of the three - strong, trip and fall?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, I want to get the mean of each column (2,3,4) for each of the graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since mean of a 2d matrix takes the mean of each column you could use

```
M = mean(weak)
plot(M(:,2:4))
```

Or if you prefer just

```
plot(mean(weak)(:,2:4))
```